# Toggle HTML Button Content when it is a SVG

Tags: html, jquery, button

**I have the following button:**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-custom rounded-0 d-flex align-items-end" href="#incendios" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#incendios" aria-expanded="false">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="25" height="25" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-arrows-expand" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
<path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M1 8a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h13a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-13A.5.5 0 0 1 1 8zM7.646.146a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0l2 2a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708L8.5 1.707V5.5a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V1.707L6.354 2.854a.5.5 0 1 1-.708-.708l2-2zM8 10a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v3.793l1.146-1.147a.5.5 0 0 1 .708.708l-2 2a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0l-2-2a.5.5 0 0 1 .708-.708L7.5 14.293V10.5A.5.5 0 0 1 8 10z" />
</svg>
<span class="visually-hidden"></span>
</button>
```

**On click, I need to change the content of the Button to a different SVG:**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-custom rounded-0 d-flex align-items-end" href="#incendios" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#incendios" aria-expanded="false">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="25" height="25" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-arrows-collapse" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
<path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M1 8a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h13a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-13A.5.5 0 0 1 1 8zm7-8a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v3.793l1.146-1.147a.5.5 0 0 1 .708.708l-2 2a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0l-2-2a.5.5 0 1 1 .708-.708L7.5 4.293V.5A.5.5 0 0 1 8 0zm-.5 11.707l-1.146 1.147a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708l2-2a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0l2 2a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708L8.5 11.707V15.5a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-3.793z" />
</svg>
<span class="visually-hidden"></span>
</button>
```

**How shoud I fix this using JQ?**

Thank you in advance for all the help.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use jq for this? Do you mean jQuery? The two are completely different tools.

Comment: Thank you... It worked... But now I have a different problem. I have several of these buttons on my page and when I click one of them, all of them change. Would you advice me to make more lines on the css with show2, hide2, show3, hide3? or a different approcach to avoid repetition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of many possibilities.

Work with two classes (`.show`, `.hide`) and toggle them:

```
$(document).on('click', 'button', function(){
  $('svg').toggleClass('show hide');
});
```

```js
$(document).on('click', 'button', function(){
  $(this).find('svg').toggleClass('show hide');
});
```

```css
.show {
  display: block;
}
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-custom rounded-0 d-flex align-items-end" href="#incendios" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#incendios" aria-expanded="false">
  <svg class="show" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="25" height="25" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-arrows-expand" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M1 8a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h13a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-13A.5.5 0 0 1 1 8zM7.646.146a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0l2 2a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708L8.5 1.707V5.5a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V1.707L6.354 2.854a.5.5 0 1 1-.708-.708l2-2zM8 10a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v3.793l1.146-1.147a.5.5 0 0 1 .708.708l-2 2a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0l-2-2a.5.5 0 0 1 .708-.708L7.5 14.293V10.5A.5.5 0 0 1 8 10z" />
  </svg>
  <svg class="hide" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="25" height="25" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-arrows-collapse" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M1 8a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h13a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-13A.5.5 0 0 1 1 8zm7-8a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v3.793l1.146-1.147a.5.5 0 0 1 .708.708l-2 2a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0l-2-2a.5.5 0 1 1 .708-.708L7.5 4.293V.5A.5.5 0 0 1 8 0zm-.5 11.707l-1.146 1.147a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708l2-2a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0l2 2a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708L8.5 11.707V15.5a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-3.793z" />
  </svg>
</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-custom rounded-0 d-flex align-items-end" href="#incendios" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#incendios" aria-expanded="false">
  <svg class="show" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="25" height="25" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-arrows-expand" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M1 8a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h13a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-13A.5.5 0 0 1 1 8zM7.646.146a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0l2 2a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708L8.5 1.707V5.5a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V1.707L6.354 2.854a.5.5 0 1 1-.708-.708l2-2zM8 10a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v3.793l1.146-1.147a.5.5 0 0 1 .708.708l-2 2a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0l-2-2a.5.5 0 0 1 .708-.708L7.5 14.293V10.5A.5.5 0 0 1 8 10z" />
  </svg>
  <svg class="hide" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="25" height="25" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-arrows-collapse" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M1 8a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h13a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-13A.5.5 0 0 1 1 8zm7-8a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v3.793l1.146-1.147a.5.5 0 0 1 .708.708l-2 2a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0l-2-2a.5.5 0 1 1 .708-.708L7.5 4.293V.5A.5.5 0 0 1 8 0zm-.5 11.707l-1.146 1.147a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708l2-2a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0l2 2a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708L8.5 11.707V15.5a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-3.793z" />
  </svg>
</button>
```

Comment: After all, I am not able to implement this with several buttons on the same page.

Comment: See the updated answer. Modified to ha dle several buttons.

Comment: I just realized I have a new problem, whenever I expand one button, I want the other buttons of the same View that are expanded to condense.
For example, at the beginning all the buttons are condensed, I want to click one of the buttons and it changes to expanded, if I click one of the other buttons, the previous button will condense and the new one will expand, and so on...